# Gmail email forwarding

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I'm using my Gmail account temporarily while I switch ISPs. I regularly use Eudora as my e-mail client. I will have close to 400 e-mails which I will need to forward to my Eudora client when my ISP changeover is complete. Is this possible? My research indicates no—hate to think I may have to forward 400 individual e-mails.

Comment: 400 email _addresses_? Or _messages_? It's unclear exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up Gmail as an IMAP account in Eudora. Let it sync your email. Then when you have your new ISP email account set up in Eudora you can drag/drop or copy/paste the emails within Eudora from the Gmail account to your new ISP account.